# Moving a transparent image in a picturebox

Tags: c#, transparency, picturebox

For a project, I'm making a game and in it I have a scrolling map. The map moves left and right and is redrawn in a picturebox so that I can have a large map in a small picturebox. The top portion of the map is transparent so that I can change the sky colour later on. However when I move the map, the transparent part glitches out.

[Original map before moving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miLZJ.jpg)

[After moving the map a bit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lU27q.jpg)

As you can see, everything above the tree line gets stretched, that is because that is where the transparency starts. The picturebox's parent is the form and the form is light blue, which is why the background is light blue.

Here is my code for moving the picture/redrawing it onto the picturebox:

```
private void timerTick_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    move();
    //Draws new portion of the map
    g.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, pbMap.Width, pbMap.Height), new Rectangle(imageX, imageY, pbMap.Width, pbMap.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    //Refreshes
    pbMap.Image = bmp;

}

private void move()
{
    //Right arrow events
    if (right)
    {
        imageX += mapSpeed;
        //Makes sure the picture stays within borders
        if (imageX >= (imageWidth - pbMap.Width))
        {
            imageX = imageWidth - pbMap.Width;
        }         
    }

    //Left arrow events
    if (left)
    {
        imageX -= mapSpeed;
        //Makes sure the picture stays within borders
        if (imageX <= 0)
        {
            imageX = 0;                 
        }      
    }
}
```

Can anyone help explain the glitching?

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `g.Clear()` with your sky color before the `g.DrawImage()` call. I think it's just drawing on top of itself and that's causing the smearing.

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems like you are redrawing over and over without clearing the display from the previous draw! What type of framework are you using to develop that? Does it have a custom drawing class? As tesserex suggested more specifically call g.Clear() and u will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need `g.Clear` in this case because you're Re-Drawing a new image every time.

My bet is that **imageX** is greater then **(imageWidth - pbMap.Width)** so it will not enter the **IF**, therefore it will redraw the same as before.

Note: I don't know how you create **g** but if you use `.CreateGraphics()` don't forget to `Dispose()`

Cheers